# Showing that a function is continuous

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $A$ be a topological space, and let $B$ be a quotient space of it. I have defined a continuous function $F:A\times[0,1]\to B$ such that it factors into a function $G:B\times[0,1]\to B$, i.e. that $F$ is the same as projecting the first argument to $B$ and then applying $G$ to the arguments. Is there now any way to show that $G$ is continuous, given that I know that $F$ is continuous?

Comment: So I guess you're saying that $F=G\circ (\gamma\;,\; $id$_{[0,1]} )$, where $\gamma:A \to B$ is the canonical quotient map?

Comment: @Shalop: Yes, that is exactly what I mean! If it would just have been something like $F=G\circ\gamma$, it would have been easier since it is a theorem that $G\circ\gamma$ is continuous if and only if $G$ is.

Answer (score 1):

So the point is that since $B$ is a quotient of $A$, then $B\times [0,1]$ is a quotient of $A\times [0,1]$.

Thus, if we let $\phi: A\times [0,1] \to B\times[0,1]$ denote the quotient map (in terms of the notation in the comments $\phi = (\gamma, id_{[0,1]})$), then we have

$F = G\circ \phi$.

Thus, since $F$ is continuous, so is $G$ by the definition of the quotient topology *on* $B\times[0,1]$.